# How to generate new random value if it already exists in the database?

Tags: php, jquery

How to automatically generate new random value in textbox if the value already exists in the database?

An example of my attempt:

```
<?php
$length = 1;
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("123456789"), 0, $length);

$mysqli1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "k");

$sql = $mysqli1->query("SELECT catid FROM subcat WHERE catid = '$randomString'");
if(($sql->num_rows) > 0){
  echo "User id exists already.";
}
echo '<input name="id" value="'.$randomString.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about what you're doing here? Are you supposed to generate a new id for each entry?

Comment: @jack I want to generate a new code in textbox if it's already a value in database.

Answer (score 0):

use this `strtotime('now')`

> **From W3schools** : strtotime parses an English textual datetime into a
>   Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00
>   GMT).

This will always be unique.So there wont be any check needed.

**Just in case if two user come simutaneously at a time**,

Append a random string..for example:

```
$unique_id=strtotime('now')."".substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 5);
```

Comment: why not just `time()`?

Comment: yus ...thats also an option

Comment: @Time_to_leave_earth what is the function of now?

Comment: @user3097736:it gives you the very current time in terms of Unix timestamp

Comment: @Time_to_leave_earth But it's too long. How about the time()?

Comment: @Time_to_leave_earth strtotime('') if there's any alternative for now?

Comment: that also gives you the unix_timestamp..try it..and use any one you like..At the end of the day..just make sure that no id is repeated twice and strtotime just exactly that

Comment: @Time_to_leave_earth strtotime('time') If I use this, it will not repeat anymore?

Comment: @user3097736:nooo..you have to use now ..thats the standard..and try googling..there are plenty of thing available on your topics

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you need an unique value

The `uniqid()` function generates a unique ID based on the microtime (current time in microseconds).

```
echo uniqid();
```

Edit:  The OP want only 6 characters. So try something like

```
$id = uniqid();
$id = substr($id,rand(0,strlen($id) - 6),6);
```

Comment: `printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());` or `echo uniqid();`

Comment: how to limit the characters into 6?

Answer (score 0):

**This will be better,** you can try this

```
$randomString = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

Comment: Why did you choose `md5()` ?

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat decently random string can be generated with this (Linux example):

```
substr(sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(3)), 0, 6);
```

Nonetheless, duplicates may occur due to the limited value domain; the following algorithm typically works:

1. Generate identifier
2. Insert record with generated identifier; use `"INSERT IGNORE"`.
3. If no affected rows, go to #1

Answer (score 0):

Generate it again.

```
<?php
$length = 1;
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("123456789"), 0, $length);

$mysqli1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "k");

$sql = $mysqli1->query("SELECT catid FROM subcat WHERE catid = '$randomString'");
if(($sql->num_rows) > 0){
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("123456789"), 0, $length);
}
echo '<input name="id" value="'.$randomString.'">';
?>
```

Or add a time at the end of the generated string to make it more random.

Something like this, and you should have a bigger length value. Because with length one, you can't have more random numbers.

```
substr(str_shuffle("123456789"), 0, $length).time();
```

But still there is chance of repeating unless you make a better algorithm using md5 or something.